# How can I detect cell text changing in VSTO add-in with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I want to use an event or something what is fired when I am typing in the cell. I tried SheetChange and SelectionChange events, which were not I need. Both of them are fired after things changed. Is there any way I can fire a event when I'm editing in a cell? Like some controls that have XXXEditing/XXXChanging events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, you can detect when the cell is in "Edit mode", i.e. is accepting input, see:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20267/Determining-if-Excel-is-in-Edit-mode

But you won't be able to detect when the user is typing anything, unless you are willing to use dirty Win32 API tricks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no event against changing cell that starts before changing it.

- change event fires after you have changed the content of the cel
- selectionchange event fires when you change the selection